# Merge skylines, divide and conquer

Tags: c#, algorithm, data-structures, divide-and-conquer

I'm trying to solve the famous skyline problem (see gif):

[image]
Input

> (1,11,5), (2,6,7), (3,13,9), (12,7,16), (14,3,25), (19,18,22), (23,13,29), (24,4,28)

Should return, the points that are behind other buildings should be gone and the coordinates of changes in the Y-axis should be in the returning skyline:

> (1, 11), (3, 13), (9, 0), (12, 7), (16, 3), (19, 18), (22, 3), (23, 13), (29, 0)

I'm trying to do so by using a divide and conquer approach to the algorithm as to achieve a running time of O(n lg n), but I'm stuck on the merge part.

Everytime I think about it I get confused. For example,  I check which one the skylines is first e.g. which has the lower x-coordinate, then I add that + its hight to my new skyline. But then I encounter a skyline thats behind two other skylines, how can I detect this 'collision'?

Do I first check if the skylines have any overlap by checking if left.x2 < right.x1? But then I think what should I check first? Overlap of precedence on the x-axis and everything turns into a big chicken-egg mess.

Maybe I'm thinking too complicated? What I need is the set of highest y coordinates, at every intersection, should I approach it like this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this should be an approach that's easier to wrap one's head around:

- Split x-coordinates into start and finish objects for each rectangle, as follows:

  ```
  rect(x1, y, x2) -> (x1, y, "start", reference to rect),
                     (x2, y, "finish", reference to rect)
  ```

  So something like:

  ```
  class MyStruct
  {
     Rectangle rect;
     int x, y;
     bool isStart;
  }
  ```
- Sort these objects by x-coordinate (`O(n log n)`)
- Create an (intially empty) set of rectangles (which will be sorted by y-coordinate, e.g. a [BST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree))
- Loop through these objects (in the now-sorted order) (`O(n)`)

  - Whenever a start is encountered

    - Add the rectangle to the set of rectangles (`O(log n)`)
    - If it's the new highest rectangle, add that start point to the output (`O(1)`)
  - Whenever a finish is encountered

    - Remove the rectangle from the set of rectangles (`O(log n)`)
    - If it's the highest rectangle, find the next highest rectangle in the set and add the point `(current.finishX, new.y)` to the output (`O(1)`) (if the set is empty, add `(current.finishX, 0)` to the output instead)

So `O(n log n)`.

Comment: Let me see If I understand correctly, by splitting the x-coordinates you mean, for example, (2, 4, 8) -> (2, 4), (8, 0), right?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not clear on what you mean by 'current rectangles'. Just a list of the initial rectangles?

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe I'm just too stupid for this, but I still don't understand. Whenever a start is encountered: add it to the set of rectangles, but we just established that these structs aren't rectangles

Comment: @Oxymoron You add the rectangle member of the object to the set.

Comment: I think there's a flaw though, between some buildings there is a gap and I think this fails to incorporate that. The gap (9,0) isn't reflected in the endresult I think.. Also, some buildings apper more than once as a building can be partly blocked from view

Comment: Ok, there was no way I wouldve come up with this myself. I'de like to explicitly thank you for this!

Comment: How is "find the next highest rectangle in the set" O(1)?

Comment: @sinoTrinity The set you're doing the lookup in is sorted by y-coordinate, and the rectangle you're looking up is the now-highest rectangle (i.e. max y-coordinate), so it will just be the last element, which can be returned in O(1) with a sorted set implementation that keeps a reference to the last element (or O(log n) for a (balanced) BST without such a reference, which doesn't change the overall time complexity).

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by modifying the algorithm for merge sort. The algorithm for skyline looks like:

**ConstructSkyLine**

```
    ConstructSkyLine(List B ) --------------- O(nlogn)
    {
        If(B.size() == 1)
        {
            List skyLineList = new List();
            SKYLINE = new SKYLINE(B.XL, B.XR, B.H);
            skyLineList.add(SKYLINE);
            Return skyLineList;
        }
        B1, B2 <-- Split(B);
        List S1 <-- ConstructSkyLine(B1);
        List S2 <-- ConstructSkyLine(B2);
        List S <-- MergeSkyline(S1, S2);
        Return S;
    }
```

**MergeSkyline**

```
    MergeSkyline(List S1, List S2) --------------- O(n)
    {
        List< SKYLINEENTRY> skylineEntryList = new ArrayList<SKYLINEENTRY>();
        while (S1.isEmpty() && S2.isEmpty())--------------- O(n)
        {
           S1Item <-- S1.get(0);
           S2Item <-- S2.get(0);
           If (S1Item.XL < S2Item.XL)
           {
             Merge(S1, S2, skylineEntryList);   --------------- O(n)
           }
           Else
           {
             Merge(S2, S1, skylineEntryList); --------------- O(n)
           }
         }

         If(!S1.isEmpty())
         {
            skylineEntryList.add(S1);
         }

         If(!S2.isEmpty())
         {
           skylineEntryList.add(S2);
         }
         Retrun skylineEntryList;
      }
```

**Merge**

```
  Merge(S1, S2, skylineEntryList) --------------- O(n)
  {
    SKYLINEENTRY <-- null;
    S1Item <-- S1.get(0);
    S2Item <-- S2.get(0);
    SKYLINEENTRY.XL = S1Item.XL;
    If(S1Item.XR > S2Item.XL) // means over lap 
    {
        If(S1Item.H > S2Item.H) // S1 is higher.
        {
           SKYLINEENTRY.XR = S1Item.XR;
           SKYLINEENTRY.H = S1Item.H;
           S1.remove(S1Item); --------------- O(n)
           skylineEntryList.add(SKYLINEENTRY);
           if(S2Item.XR < S1Item.XR) // full overlap
           {
              S2.remove(S2Item); --------------- O(n)
           }
           Else // partial overlap
           {
              S2Item.XL <-- S1Item.XR;
           }            
        }
        Else //S2 is higher
        {
           SKYLINEENTRY.XR = S2Item.XL;
           SKYLINEENTRY.H = S1Item.H;
           if(S2Item.XR < S1Item.XR) // full overlap with S2
           {
              S1Item.XL = S2Item.XR;
           }
           Else // partial overlap
           {
              S1.remove(S1Item); --------------- O(n)
           }    
           skylineEntryList.add(SKYLINEENTRY);  
        }   
     }
     Else // no overlap
     {
        SKYLINEENTRY.XR = S1Item.XR;
        SKYLINEENTRY.H = S1Item.H;
        S1.remove(S1Item); --------------- O(n)
        skylineEntryList.add(SKYLINEENTRY);
     }
  }
```