# Java libGDX - merge polygons

Tags: java, merge, polygon

I'm working at a underwater game, where there are some ruins, made out of blocks.
Currently, I am checking for collision with the submarine's polygon and each block of the ruin, with a function that returns the vertices of a rectangle that I made.

```
public static float[] rectangleToVertices(float x, float y, float width,
            float height) {
        float[] result = new float[8];
        result[0] = x;
        result[1] = y;

        result[2] = x + width;
        result[3] = y;

        result[4] = x + width;
        result[5] = y + height;
        result[6] = x;
        result[7] = y + height;

        return result;
    }
```

I don't think that is very efficient, some of the ruins got over 10 blocks, and I don't want to check for 10 times a collision of a single object.
Is there a way to merge more polygons into one?

This picture can explain better:
[image]

There red area is the polygon.

Comment: You should use an array of Point class (or your own class) not a float array where pairs of variables are stored consecutively. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html

Comment: Where is the picture? I cannot see that

Comment: @Arash, i can, anyways - http://i.stack.imgur.com/7juGq.png

Comment: @Paul, can you please accept the answer if you find it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, you are removing `shared` edges.

The simplest solution would be to start with one block, adding its edges to a `HashSet` (say S1). Then, while iterating over the list of blocks, check if any of those other blocks shares any edge from S1. If so, add all edges of that block to S1. For the edge(s) which already existed in S1, add them to another `HashSet` (say S2) to keep track of such edges. In the end, compute S1-S2, which will be the set of edges that you want. Use those edges to reconstruct your final polygon.

As an aside, you might want to take a look at [The Skyline Problem‍​​](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066234/the-skyline-problem).

Comment: This will generate a 'group' for each group of adjacent blocks. You can repeat this for the remaining blocks until all blocks are groupified.

Comment: This will work and group all blocks as long as the vertices line up